# AngularJS Post Method RESTFUL

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, post

I have an Angular Controller, a factory service and a *app.js*.
There is also a `MongoDB` in the background. So i have a `GET` Method and it's already running very well. But how do i create a post method over `HTTP`? 
So there is a formular as a html file. There are some `CheckBoxes` and input fields. `AngularJS` i use for the Frontend, in the background theres a JAVA Program.

Comment: take a look at the [$http service docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below shorthand syntax for GET and POST requests: 
GET: `$http.get('/URL').success(successCallback);`

POST: `$http.post('/URL', data).success(successCallback);`

Refer to [this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for details on how to set different parameters. You may also have a look at tutorials [here](http://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2014/02/26/angular-js-blog-series-table-of-content/).